# How to eagerly load unassociated active model records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, eager-loading

I have two models: `Hurricane` and `Problem` and each `Hurricane` has many `Problem`

Now in my database I want to let users update data about each Hurricane, so I have one copy of the data that is set by the admin and each user has access to this data. When each user wants to update data about the Hurricane, I create a new copy of the admin created record and scope it so that each user sees only the newly created record that they modified. And each new record stores and 'original_id' attribute that stores the id of the model it was cloned from. However, each Problem model will still point to the original Hurricane record (created by the admin). I should also mention that each problem is `belongs_to` a `User`

For a given user, when listing all the problems, I'd like to eagerly load all the associated Hurricanes, and instead of displaying the Hurricanes that they point to, I'd like to eagerly load the ones that they modified

I tried this:

In my `app/models/problem.rb`

```
class Problem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hurricane
  belongs_to :user_hurricane, -> (problem) { where "original_id = ? AND user_id = ?", problem.hurricane_id, problem.user_id }, class_name: 'Hurricane'
  ...
```

Then I call some think like the following

```
problems = Problem.includes(:user_hurricanes).where(user_id: current_user.id)
problems.each do |problem|
  puts problem.user_hurricane
end
# >> always returns nil
```

But the user_hurricane is always nil, so it doesn't successfully eagerly load the user specific Hurricane records. How would I do that?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes

Comment: I should have been more clear. I do use the 'includes' method in my controller, but it doesn't work for me. I've updated the question so that is more clear.

Comment: eager loading a dynamic association is not possible as far as i know

Comment: Thanks @phoet! I suspected just as much.